# Way to delay/timeout postback in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback

Is there any way to delay/timeout a postback from listview button in jQuery? I would like to make fadeOut animation before postback, which is firing when button is clicked. Any ideas?

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btndown').click(function () {
        $('.imageset').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Button markup, which is getting postback when it's clicked:

```
<div class="btndown">
      <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager2" runat="server" PagedControlID="Listview1" PageSize="3">
            <Fields>
                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Image" FirstPageText="" LastPageText="" NextPageImageUrl="~/images/arrowbtndown.png" NextPageText="" PreviousPageText="" ShowPreviousPageButton="False"/>
            </Fields>
      </asp:DataPager>
</div>
```

Button output:

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DataPager2$ctl00$ctl00" src="images/arrowbtndown.png">
```

Comment: What does your postback look like? Provide that too.

Comment: The postback is changing page in listview. I would like to fadeOut it before postback, because on pageLoad I've got fadeIn, so it would be a smooth fadeOut/fadeIn effect.

Comment: @Ashiv3r: post your button markup , n when its get postback ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a timeout, use the [animation complete callback](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```
// This stops the `postback` from being fired on the `<asp>` generated button.
$('.btndown input').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.btndown').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.imageset').animate({
       'opacity': 0
    }, 1000, function() {
          // Animation has completed
          // Trigger the 'postback' JS function, whatever this may be.
    });
});
```

Depending on what this outputs:

```
<asp:DataPager ID="DataPager2" runat="server" PagedControlID="Listview1" PageSize="3">
        <Fields>
           <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Image" FirstPageText="" LastPageText="" NextPageImageUrl="~/images/arrowbtndown.png" NextPageText="" PreviousPageText="" ShowPreviousPageButton="False"/>
        </Fields>
 </asp:DataPager>
```

will make a difference as what this outputs could trigger the postback right away on click. If you share the final output it might help more.

Comment: Final output:
<input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DataPager2$ctl00$ctl00" src="images/arrowbtndown.png">.
Unfortunately your jQuery doesn't work too.

Comment: My code snippet is just the animation part, you need to disable the `<input/>` and then trigger the `postback` function manually in the animation complete callback I have mentioned. I don't know what javascript events are bound to the `<asp>` button. You need to find out more about what that button does with JS. You can stop it triggering by doing `$('.btndown input').click(function(e){e.preventDefault()});`.

Comment: I need to pass on postback my .btndown name attribute, but I don't know how can I do this inside __doPostBack();

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Final solution under:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function pageLoad() {

    $('.btndown').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.imageset').animate({
          opacity: 0
          }, 1000, function () {
                 __doPostBack($('.btndown input').attr('name'), '');
          });
    });
};
</script>
```